# Redirect after submission (in hosted version of Form.io)

Tags: formio

Can we redirect to another page/form after successful form submission, in the cloud version of Form.io? I'm thinking about redirecting to another form after a user authenticates but this would also be used to more general page navigation too.

I can't see any Actions that would do this, and I don't think (please correct me if I'm wrong) I have access to the events discussed in the tutorials for the self-hosted version.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by attaching an event handler on the form renderer and then manually redirecting after the form has submitted. Assuming you are using `ng2-formio` as your renderer, you would do this as follows.

```
<formio src="https://examples.form.io/example" (submit)="(function(submission) {

  window.location.href = 'https://form.io';

})($event)"></formio>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just [posting a link to the answer from the docs with promises](https://github.com/formio/formio.js/wiki/Form-Renderer#events) for reference because I found them handy.

```
Formio.createForm(document.getElementById('formio'), 'https://examples.form.io/example')
.then(function(form) {
  form.on('submit', (submission) => {
    window.location.href = 'https://form.io';
  });
  form.on('error', (errors) => {
    console.log('We have errors!');
  })
});
```

The docs were written by [Travis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4157958/travis-tidwell) from the accepted answer, btw.